# scrolling issue in android webview whch is inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, webview

I have following format.

1) ListView.
List Row.textview and  WebView which is inside Framelayout. The xml file is as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapterTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chapterWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/custom_gray_dark"
        android:visibility="gone" >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/chapterHtmlWebView"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i need to show this webview in specific size under ListItem when user click on textview which is before it. Now when the content is bigger the webview is not able to scroll at down. Another restriction is ListView should not scrooll when web view is visible.  To handle the click and scroll event i am trying to handle that event in FrameLayout (onInterceptTouchEvent() )which is parent of webview but for that i need to return the true in onTouchEvent() of ListView. In that case i can not handle the click event on Other list item. The basic problem is Click and scroll event is not working in WebView which is inside each row of ListView. So can some one suuggest better way to handle this click event with combination of ListView, WebView, Framelayout which is parent of WebvIEW.